# How to list all user defined functions called within functions or user defined functions with pryr package in R?

Tags: r

Basically I need to find out **list of functions / user defined functions** or a **treemap** or **hierarchy of useful functions** & **trace them to the last leaf** to understand the business logic behind it & recode it if possible.

Recently I posted a similar Question & was directed to check a post on **pryr** package: [How can I list all user defined functions called within functions or user defined functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645606/how-can-i-list-all-user-defined-functions-called-within-functions-or-user-define)

**Issue:** when I execute `call_tree(parse(text=user_defined_function()))` I get an error & since the earlier post was marked duplicate too quickly, I can't ask there.

**My Attempt:**  (dummy data)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(pryr)

test_df <- data.frame(id = c(1234, 1234, 5678, 5678),
           date = c("2021-10-10","2021-10-10", "2021-8-10", "2021-8-15"),
           Amount  = c(54767, 96896, 34534, 79870),
           type = c("lt","mt","mt","mt")) %>% 
  
  mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

```
plt_test_df <- function(type_value = "mt"){
  test_df %>% 
  filter(type == type_value) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Amount)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE, size = 0.8) +
  geom_point()
}
```

When I try to trace this function, I get an error:

```
trace_func_depth <- capture.output(pryr::call_tree(parse(text = plt_test_df())))
```

**Error:**

```
Error in parse(text = plt_test_df()) : <text>:2:6: unexpected '<'
1: list(id = c(1234, 5678, 5678), date = c(18910, 18849, 18854), Amount = c(96896, 34534, 79870), type = c("mt", "mt", "mt"))
2: list(<
^
```

If this is not working with **user defined function** names then will this work in tracing those user defined functions & within them that are called within the user defined functions itself??

Is there any library that can build tree level structure for user defined functions & go in depth to trace all the user defined functions called with in. I am not sure if this `pryr` can do that.

**This seems to work only when I pass complete function instead of just function name:**

```
trace_func_depth <- capture.output(pryr::call_tree(parse(text = "test_df %>% 
  filter(type == 'mt') %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = Amount)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5, show.legend = FALSE, size = 0.8) +
  geom_point()")))

trace_func_depth
```

```
[1] "\\- ()"                  "  \\- `+"                "  \\- ()"               
 [4] "    \\- `+"              "    \\- ()"              "      \\- `%>%"         
 [7] "      \\- ()"            "        \\- `%>%"        "        \\- `test_df"   
[10] "        \\- ()"          "          \\- `filter"   "          \\- ()"       
[13] "            \\- `=="     "            \\- `type"   "            \\-  \"mt\""
[16] "      \\- ()"            "        \\- `ggplot"     "        \\- ()"         
[19] "          \\- `aes"      "          \\- `date"     "          \\- `Amount"  
[22] "    \\- ()"              "      \\- `geom_line"    "      \\-  0.5"         
[25] "      \\-  FALSE"        "      \\-  0.8"          "  \\- ()"               
[28] "    \\- `geom_point "
```

Comment: First a note:  if something is marked as a duplicate but it's not, you can edit the question to point out what's new, and it might be re-opened.  Or you can post a new question, as you did here.

Comment: Now an approach, not an answer: you tried to call `parse(text = plt_test_df())`, and that doesn't make sense. That calls your `plt_test_df` function, and then tries to parse the result, which is some kind of ggplot2 object, not text. You should pass `plt_test_df` itself to a function that understands call trees, e.g. `pryr::call_tree(body(plt_test_df))` (though this misses function calls in the args).

Comment: Now some discouragement:  you can't tell from looking at the code whether a function is user-defined or not.  I can define my own function called `mean`, and call it sometimes, the standard ones other times, and you basically need to evaluate the code to know which one was called.  E.g. `if (runif(1) < 0.5) mean <- function(...) print("mine!") else mean <- base::mean`.

Comment: Thanks @user2554330 for sharing info on `udf` & `pryr::call_tree(body(plt_test_df))`. I think this should do & will explore them. Thanks again!!